# Model not visible android OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am currently trying to display my model I exported from blender.  I have parsed this file and have 2 arrays, one of which holds the vertex data and the other holds the index data. My bindData method binds the vertex data to the shader program.  The problem I am encountering is that the asteroid is not being drawn(or they are being drawn but cannot see them).  I can provide more code or clarify my problem further if needed.

```
public Asteroid(){
    vertexArray = new VertexArray(AsteroidFinal.VERTEX_ARRAY);

    indexBuffer = ByteBuffer
            .allocateDirect(AsteroidFinal.INDICES_ARRAY.length * 2)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            .asShortBuffer()
            .put((short) AsteroidFinal.INDICES_ARRAY.length);
    indexBuffer.position(0);
}


public void bindData(ColorShaderProgram colorProgram){
      vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(
                0, 
                colorProgram.getPositionAttributeLocation(), 
                POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT,
                0);
}

public void draw(){
    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertexCount);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, AsteroidFinal.INDICES_ARRAY.length, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the drawing surface is visible?  e.g. glClear() to red gives you a red screen?  Are you able to draw other shapes, but just not this particular one?  (Seeing nothing on screen is a pretty common problem, but there's a lot of different possible causes.)

Comment: @fadden I have been able to draw a quad with almost the same code with the exception of allocation of the indexBuffer and changing glDrawArrays to glDrawElements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not storing the indices in the index buffer:

```
indexBuffer = ByteBuffer
        .allocateDirect(AsteroidFinal.INDICES_ARRAY.length * 2)
        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        .asShortBuffer()
        .put((short) AsteroidFinal.INDICES_ARRAY.length);
```

This adds the length of the array to the buffer, not the actual array values. It should be:

```
indexBuffer = ByteBuffer
        .allocateDirect(AsteroidFinal.INDICES_ARRAY.length * 2)
        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        .asShortBuffer()
        .put(AsteroidFinal.INDICES_ARRAY);
```